# Select gray patches from an image in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I have a picture of 12 white to black patches with a gray background and I am trying to write a code in MATLAB to select these 12 patches. The problem I am facing is that some patches are not detected properly as shown in the 2nd image.

**Input image**

[image: Image to process]

**Code Output**

[image: Code Output]

My questions are:

1. How can I correctly select these 12 ROIs?
2. Is there is any better and perfect way to do it in MATLAB?

**My implementation**:

```
CropImg=imread('patchc.jpg');
img=rgb2gray(CropImg);
rangefiltv= rangefilt(img);
imshow(rangefiltv)
mask = rangefiltv >10;
mask=~mask;
mask = bwareafilt(mask, 12);
stat = regionprops(mask,'boundingbox');
imshow(CropImg); hold on;
for cnt = 1 : numel(stat)
    bb = stat(cnt).BoundingBox;
    rectangle('position',bb,'edgecolor','r','linewidth',2);
end
```